# Matching number in three files not shown

Tags: java

The program I am coding allows the user to find a matching credit card number in three text files. However, it outputs that no matches have been found in any of the comparisons between the files. If someone could guide me on how to fix this problem, that would be great! Down below is the code for the program.

Edit: it seems that I forgot to place the number 1000 in some of the comparisons between the files. I now have a null exception problem at
             if(numbers1[i].compareTo(numbers2[i]) == 0){

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MatchingNumber {
public static int counter = 0;
public static int flag;
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
static BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
static BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
static int x; 
static String[] numbers1 = new String[1000];  
static String[] numbers2 = new String[1000];
static String[] numbers3 = new String[1000];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    loadNumbers();
    firstCompare();
    secondCompare();
    thirdCompare();
}
public static void loadNumbers() throws IOException {

    String findFile, file;
    //ask for location of file
    System.out.println("Enter File 1 Location: ");
    //Read input
    findFile = in.readLine();
    //find file
    file = findFile + "/creditCards1.txt";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String findFile1, file1;
    //ask for location of file
    System.out.println("Enter File 2 Location: ");
    //Read input
    findFile1 = in2.readLine();
    //find file
    file1 = findFile1 + "/creditCards2.txt";
    BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

    String findFile2,file2;
    //ask for location of file
    System.out.println("Enter File 3 Location: ");
    //Read input
    findFile2 = in3.readLine();
    //find file
    file2 = findFile2 + "/creditCards3.txt";
    BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));


    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            //read in the data
            numbers1[i] = in.readLine();
            numbers2[i] = in2.readLine();
            numbers3[i] = in3.readLine();
            counter++;             
        }
     in.close();   
     in2.close();
     in3.close();
}

public static void firstCompare() {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if(numbers1[i].compareTo(numbers2[i]) == 0){
            flag = i;
            found = true;
            System.out.println(flag + "is the matching number in files 1 and 2");
        }
    }
    if (!found){
        System.out.println("No matches found files 1 and 2");

    }
}

    public static void secondCompare() {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            if(numbers1[i].compareTo(numbers3[i]) == 0){
                flag = i;
                found = true;
                System.out.println(flag + "is the matching number in files 1 and 3");
            }
        }
        if (!found){
            System.out.println("No matches found files 1 and 3");
    }
}

    public static void thirdCompare() {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            if(numbers2[i].compareTo(numbers3[i]) == 0){
                flag = i;
                found = true;
                System.out.println(flag + "is the matching number in files 2 and 3");
            }
        }
        if (!found){
            System.out.println("No matches found files 2 and 3");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Two numbers match if they are equal and in the same position within two files? If not, you'll need two variables to iterate through the "files" independently.

Comment: A second source of problems is the formatting of the numbers. "1234 5678 1234 5678" is not equal to "1234 5678 1234 5678 " or "1234567812345678" (just as an example), but can be considered equal CC numbers. I'd try to convert them all to the same format while reading them (e.g. throw away every non-digit).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you limit your amount of credit card numbers?

```
static String[] numbers1 = new String[1000];  
static String[] numbers2 = new String[1000];
static String[] numbers3 = new String[1000];
```

I would recommend using:

```
static List<String> numbers1 = new List<String>();
static List<String> numbers2 = new List<String>();
static List<String> numbers3 = new List<String>();
```

This will allow you to increase your project's scalability and reduce redundancy when comparing.

When comparing, you can simply loop through one list and check if another list contains the element that you are looking for:

```
boolean found = false;
int i = 0;
while(!found)
{
    if(numbers1.Contains(numbers2[i])
        found = true;
    i++;
}
```